# Odd artifact in mesh only when rendering in cycles, starts at third frame

Tags: rendering, mesh

Fairly new to Blender, having a confusing problem.

Have added some embossings to this book which was causing me some problems to get to not deform the initial book mesh. Eventually got there with that.

Now when I look at it in the viewport everything is great. 
When I render out a 360 rotation animation in Eevee everything is great.
When I try to render out in cycles I'm getting this odd deformation starting at the third frame. Have checked if everything is unchecked, if textures are the problem etc. Theres not even a mesh line there, very confused.

Any help appreciated. Heres the blender file - https://we.tl/t-UuJ7ov2Lhp

[image]

Comment: I couldn't see the glitch from my end but it's most likely an n-gon shading glitch. For future reference, consider using a different workflow to create the embossment. I take it that you imported an image, added depth to it and used a boolean to create the embossing. This creates a metric ton of bad topology and potential shading issues as vklidu already noticed. Instead, consider manipulating the image into a *displacement map*, or baking a displacement map from the embossed book onto the non-embossed book.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the help! 
I started again with a displacement map workflow and got much better looking results and no glitching :)

Answer (score 1):

One additional cut it solved.

[image]

---

But ... I cant find what it cause. I checked face orientation, shading type collision, make face planar, deleted all 88 thousand duplications (merge by distance), deleted all from scene (if it is not in hidden, isolated problematic face, unpluged material, tried Normals ... but nothing affect the issue. Only triangulation. Limited disolve to make n-gon back, brought issue back. Now Im interersted too :)

Definetely overlapping faces like n-gon tries to connect in two sharp angle?

[image]

Comment: If you found it as correct, consider mark Answer as Solved (by click on checkmark symbol) so others can see it from main list. You can uncheck any time. Thank you